# Are match statements executed in order and can they overlap?

Tags: rust

The documentation isn't clear on this...are the cases in a `match` statement guaranteed to be executed in order? In the case of don't-care matches, is it OK to have overlapping matches?

```
let a: bool;
let b: bool;
let c: bool;
let d: bool;

match (a, b, c, d) {
    (true, _, _, _) => { /* ... */ }
    (_, true, _, _) => { /* ... */ }
}
```

Essentially, can Rust's `match` be used as a weird sort of case filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the match statements are guaranteed to be executed in order. These two matches are equivalent:

```
match (a, b) {
    (true, _) => println!("first is true !"),
    (_, true) => println!("second is true !"),
    (_, _) => println!("none is true !"),
}

match (a, b) {
    (true, _) => println!("first is true !"),
    (false, true) => println!("second is true !"),
    (false, false) => println!("none is true !"),
}
```

Comment: Interesting...if you could supply custom matchers, this could make some very, very weird code.

Comment: Seems like the optimiser could choose to do things in other orders: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/pqnufj/rust_match_arm_priority/